# can't convert string to integer-python

Tags: python, string, dictionary, tuples

I have a string within a tuple like this:

```
params': {
    'rtinseconds': '57.132',
    **'charge': '3+'**, 
    'pepmass': (822.6547241, None), 
    title': '20130630_006.d, MS/MS of 822.6547241 3+ at 0.9522 mins'
}
```

I am trying to read and convert the value of charge '3+' to integer value 3.

I tried the following code where I read the first character in the string and stored it in a separate variable, then tried to convert it to int, but does not work. The type of 3 is still str. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
        temp_z = item['params']['charge']
        z = temp_z[0:1]
        str(z)
        int(z)
```

Comment: `z = int(temp_z[0:1])`, `int` returns a new object.

Comment: as an aside, it might be better for you to use `z = int(temp_z.replace("+",""))`, on the off chance that the charge is ever more than 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the simple case:

```
z = int(params['charge'].replace('+',''))
```

However if it is possible that your item may have a negative charge you may want:

```
if '+' in params['charge']:
    z = int(params['charge'].replace('+',''))
else:
    z = -int(params['charge'].replace('-',''))
```